# Personalization of WordPress search results including some pages and some categories and all product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want the search results based on my desired pages (for example, the about us and contact us page are not in the search results), the categories I want (for example, only articles with Comedy and Action categories are in the results) and also all the products of the site without Considering the display category.

Please teach how to filter based on the name of the category or pages and... and based on ID.

**I have the following code, but it is not complete:**

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','exclude_categories_from_search');
function exclude_categories_from_search($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        
        $post_term_names = array( 'comedy' , 'action' ); 
        $taxquery = array(
            
            'post_type'              => array( 'post' , 'product' , 'page' ), 
            'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ), 
            'posts_per_page'         => '-1', 
            'order'                  => 'DESC',
            'orderby'                => 'date',
            'tax_query'              => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'         => 'category',
                        'terms'            => $post_term_names, 
                        'field'            => 'slug',
                        'operator'         => 'IN',
                        'include_children' => true,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'         => 'product_cat',
                        'terms'            => 'all', // and -1 not work
                        'field'            => 'slug',
                        'operator'         => 'IN',
                        'include_children' => true,
                    ),
            ),
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

The code above does not search pages.

The above code does not search all products.

---

**Off topic question:**
What is the use of `$query->is_main_query()` and what exactly does it do?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Thank you for your guidance.    
Can you help me solve this problem?